# How do I find which component installed timespan 2.3.0?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular CLI application running with a node.js server.

A security scan of my application blocked "timespan: 2.3.0" because of a vulnerability.

I do not have "timespan": "2.3.0" in my package.json file.

How can I find out where this is being installed from?

I have searched my project and the node_modules folder for "timespan" but could not find it.

Does anyone know how to find it or fix this error?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: If you type `npm list` within your project folder, you should get an output of all the installed packages in a tree format that shows which package is a dependency of another. Perhaps you will be able to find the package in this list.

Comment: `npm ls timespan`

Comment: That worked! Thanks